# cannot delete a field refered in the flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

I am new to flows, trying to delete a field which is referenced in the flow, I have DE-referecned/deleted the field from a screen flow and created a new version of it. Deleted all the inactive old versions.

When I click on "where is this used" button, field  still it says referenced in the screen flow. Not able figure out why it still shows the reference.

Comment: Did you tried something like below. Save As either a new version or new flow and delete the flows that access the field. Then in the new Flow or version remove the reference to the field, delete the old versions.

Comment: field removed from all assignment blocks? all get record elements? all update record elements? all flow formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was referenced in one of the formula field. deleted there and it worked.